# openam + adfs test fedration fails

Tags: adfs2.0, openam

I referred this site : https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+and+ADFS2+configuration
for the setup of openam + adfs and followed all the steps from the document but when test it using the link: (link similar to my setup)

https://sso.aaa.local:8443/opensso/saml2/jsp/spSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/sp&NameIDFormat=transient&idpEntityID=http://IDP01.bbb.local/adfs/services/trust&binding=HTTP-POST

from any browser I get this error:
IDP01.bbb.local :: web page not found and so on.

it is redirecting to :

https://IDP01.bbb.local/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=.....//some code......

This test is done from network A and network B but same error is coming.

So please can anyone help me with this exception and tell me the possible solution for it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to perfom 'IdP-initiated SSO' as mentioned in the wiki article ... this might first be easier.

You may also look at the SAML protocol messages, e.g. using 'SAML tracer' plugin for Firefox.

This may help you to understand the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the above SAMLRequest - to do that have a look at [ADFS : I want to see the SAML data](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/adfs-i-want-to-see-saml-data.html).

Then have a look at the URL's inside the request - my guess is one of them is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you should pay attention which information you post to the public if you want to hide your setup ... the SAML authentication request shows your server FQDN ...